# How to make a grid layout with unknown number of columns and each column has equal size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make a row of columns where columns number could be from 5 to 10, and width of each column should be equal, how can I achieve this by using css only and not using `<table>`?

Right now I'm using a bootstrap but it has fixed sizes only. All solutions which I've found by googling right now are evolving using `<table>` element, but as far as I know it's wrong approach and I have heard many times not to use `<table>` for templating.

The most elegant solution which I've thought about till now (not tested yet) is to calculate width dynamically by `javascript` and change it on fly, is there another, better approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

The parent element should have `display: flex` in its CSS. Each of its children (the columns) should have `flex: 1` (this allows the element to shrink and grow as much as possible regardless of the contents).

Here's an example:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Contents don't matter for width.</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is good! But what about compatibility?

Comment: Great, it exactly what I was need!

Comment: **the newest versions** sometimes is not sufficient. In my opinion, flexbox is good, but in my work is impossible to use it yet, there are so many people browsing with IE8 / IE9 and something like this

Comment: I don't downvote you

Comment: Android browsers, IE8 / 9 / 10 has none or bad compatibility, iOS and Safari only with prefixes, etc. This is as when we write 5 properties and includes one or more javascript plugins to achieve a border radius. I like flexbox, but is not usable for production purposes yet, if you have important clients and you are not only playing with css

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Your solution is actually quite good for those cases! I've found that you are safe to use flexbox since a very large percentage of web users are browsing on up-to-date browsers. :) A good solution would be flexbox, and wrapping your solution in an IE9 CSS hack.

Comment: Yeah, enterprise application developers face this the most since corporations and governments are usually very, very slow at adopting new tech.

Answer (score 1):

You can use display, to compatibility with all browsers:

CSS:

```
    .table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table .row {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .table .row .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jsfiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/4be2dhb2

Good luck!